# Problem in writing output file in jmeter maven project

Tags: maven, testing, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using beanshell postprocessor to write a file in my jmeter script,when I run this script as a maven project the file is being written into the
target folder. I want it to be written inside the src/test/jmeter of my project. How can I achieve this. I'm new in my testing journey so if you find my question silly spare and help me

I tried using the userpropertiesin my pom.xml, also I tried using the maven resource plugin to copy the file from Target to src/test/jmeter.

**Edit**:

I have created a folder structure like

- `src/test/jmeter/test_folder/test file.csv`
- `src/test/jmeter/test_folder/testplan.jmx`

When I try to add the testfile.csv as a input by using csvdatasetconfig element,by giving the relative address as `./testfile.csv`,the test plan works inside the jmeter ui,but when i it run from my maven project the `testfile.csv` is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) sets JMeter basedir / working directory to a very specific location, you can determine it from [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

```
2023-10-11 16:58:47,475 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/path/to/your/project/target/some-guid/jmeter/bin
```

so you need to get 4 levels up in order to get to your project directory and then navigate to target directory.

Instead of:

```
new File("somefile.txt")
```

you need to use a [relative path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm), something like:

```
new File("../../../../src/test/jmeter/somefile.txt")
```

---

In general your approach seems not too good to me:

1. First of all, using Beanshell is kind of performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting. See [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) for more details.
2. If there will be multiple users writing into the same file you will face data corruption/loss due to race conditions, it makes sense to consider using [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) instead.

Comment: Your solution to the original question worked, have edited my question.